# In Dual monitor mode touch works on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-touch

I use Asus Vivobook S500, and when connecting second monitor i had problem with calibration.
I entered these commands:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --off
xinput map-to-output "Virtual core pointer" LVDS1
```

enabled second monitor from Settings-->Displays.
No, when I'm touching monitor mouse appears in second display.
What is wrong and how to solve it?
Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3046 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+   60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 34:DF:2A:0C:F3:56
```

PS. xsetwacom --list not giving any output.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using device name from xinput:

```
xsetwacom set "Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer" MapToOutput LVDS1
```